# Google Datastudio getting NULL value with the function TODATE

Tags: looker-studio

I'm trying to use the function TODATE and it seems not to be working. I used the this formula:

```
TODATE(Send Time, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M', '%Y/%m/%d')
```

But it keeps getting "NULL"

Please see screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: Could you elaborate by providing a publicly editable Google Data Studio Report (additionally, a Google Sheet if it's the data set) of the scenario (using sample data that shows 1) Input values (~10 rows) 2) Expected output 3) An attempt at solving the issue)? It would help users visualise the issue and test out suggestions on a specific use case with objective right / wrong answers. Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it would be difficult to pinpoint a suggestion and the issue, e.g. Data Set, Data Source, Report, Fields, Chart

Answer (score -1):

In your example Send Time appears to be formatted as a Datetime but I believe the Input format you are using in TODATE needs to be a string. Have you tried changing the format to string?